# Exception handling continue on error and then rethrow

Tags: java, exception

```
     //Assume list1 and list2 are populated with states as 2
    foo (List<Class1> list1, List <Class1> list2) {

         boolean error = false;
          try {
             operate on list1
         } catch (Exception e) {
              error = true;
             //Modify list1 objects to state 1
        }

          try {
             operate on list2
         } catch (Exception e) {
              error = true;
             //Modify list2 objects to state 1
         }

        //What are the problems and what is the best practice for this
         if (error)
             throw new Exception(…);  //How should i really rethrow the exception

    }
```

Comment: Is that design sensible? What's the point of operating on list2 if the first operation already had an error and you're only going to throw an exception anyway? Why not throw right away?

Answer (score 2):

The main improvement I'd make is to store all exceptions that occur and make them available somehow, somewhere. Otherwise, it seems fine.

To the skeptical, it's not really abnormal to want to complete some work even when an exception happens. Batch processing is a pretty typical case.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing technically wrong with it, other than getting the `throws` clause correct, etc.  You could even save one of the caught exceptions and re-throw it.

Not clear why you'd want to do this, but I've done weirder.